# Training loss and validation loss spike inbetween training

Tags: python, tensorflow, validation, keras, loss

Here is my model and how I fit and train it. I am using a GRU model for NLP Generation. It starts off running well but around the 15th epoch everything just changes. I don't know what to attribute to that just yet.

```
 # Define a simple sequential model
  def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(256, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(512, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(700))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(train_Y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))


 model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=[tf.metrics.CategoricalCrossentropy(), 'accuracy'])

return model


# Create a basic model instance
model = create_model()

# Display the model's architecture
model.summary()
```

Here is the fitting and saving of the model code:

```
checkpoint_path = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/NLP/training_4/cp.ckpt"
#checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                             save_weights_only=True,
                                             save_best_only = True,
                                             verbose=1)

# Train the model with the new callback
history = model.fit(train_X, 
      train_Y,  
      epochs=50,
      batch_size = 50,
      validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid),
      callbacks=[cp_callback])  # Pass callback to training
```

[This is the plotted training and validation loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfaJN.png)
Apparently I can't display an image just yet as I need to get reputation points.

What can I do to rectify this please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't add your code as a pic, and share the details of the data and the model such as LR, optimizer etc.

Comment: Thank you, I just modified it now.

Comment: try reducing learning rate, or use decaying learning rate

Comment: Ok, thanks Andrey. I will give it a go